Enable shadow copy on a single folder only in Windows 10
I have a specific folder (with files and subfolders) on my computer, that I would like to enable previous versions on. Is this possible in Windows 10 or can I only enable it for an entire drive?
My idea was to attach a secondary hard drive and have Windows 10 mirror all changes to my specific folder onto that drive while having the ability to use previous versions to manage restore functionality.
I hope I'm not mixing stuff up here...

The only way to keep previous copies of a folder is if you enable it for the entire drive. You can move the folder to a drive, where that is the only thing contain on it, that is the closest you can get to your goal.

Windows' built-in Previous Versions function is limited to full-drive protection because it is based on a full-drive protection/backup technology called Volume Shadow Copies, which allows for very low resource usage of the backup system and backing up locked, in use, and protected files.
If you really only want to protect a single folder you have to use other methods. Here are two I can think of:

Move that folder to the secondary hard drive and enable the recovery functions on that drive.
Use an alternate backup tool that offers single-folder protection options.


I had a feeling that my idea was too good to be possible  I thought about your second point, but your first suggestion is actually a clever way of working around the current limitations! Thanks!
